# Error to get contactID in iOS8 - Crash

Tags: ios, crash, ios8, contacts

I have been working in an iOS app, when i need to get contact information from the cellphone, this is my code:

```
ABRecordID contactID = ABRecordGetRecordID(contact);
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil);
ABRecordRef origContactRef = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, contactID);

CFRetain(origContactRef);
...
...
...
CFRelease(origContactRef);
```

The problem is in iOS8, in this line:
`CFRetain(origContactRef);`

Because the object is null.

How can i fix it?

Greeting.

Comment: Are `contactID` and `addressBook ` good?

Comment: This is the result:
contactID = -1
addressBook = <ABCAddressBook 0x7fca6971c4a0 [0x10b9ff9a0]>
origContactRef = (null)

Answer (score 0):

If contactID is -1 then the rest of the following statements will fail.

In this case the -1 indicates the record is not found.

You need to check for errors whenever they may occur, you can not just assume every method call will succeed. In this case the first place to check for an error is on the `ABRecordGetRecordID` statement.

From the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABRecordRef_iPhoneOS/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABRecordGetRecordID):

> ABRecordGetRecordID
>
> Return Value The unique ID of record when the record exists in the
>   Address Book database.
>
> kABRecordInvalidID when the record hasn’t been saved to the database.

and

`#define kABRecordInvalidID  -1`

Comment: Okay, thank you, but what is the difference between ios8 and ios7?, because in ios7 works fine.

Comment: Different contact or contact details? Why does it fail now, does `contact` have a match in Contacts? Is the ABRecord good, is also nil? Really examine your code and the results of each method call. Check all method call for failure if they can fail. Catch the error as early as possible.